# What is a War Like?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

In the film, "Go Tell the Spartans" (1978), U.S. Major Asa Barker asks young Corporal Courcey why he has volunteered to spend the last six-months of his military service, fighting in Viet Nam. After some hesitation the Corporal mumbles: "Well, Sir...I wanted to see what a war was like.".

In Latin?

This is direct speech which includes an indirect question, requiring an interrogative and a verb in the subjunctive (in the same tense as the English). The nearest-fit verb to the English, "like", as in "resembling something" would appear to be the intransitive, "similis sum" (Oxford).

> "Cupiebam scire quid bellum similis esset."
> =
> "I wanted to know what a war was resembling / was (like)."

If Corporal Courcey had chosen to complete his service in more sedate circumstances, he may well have always wondered what a war would have been like. This is more difficult, requiring, in the indirect question, a periphrastic pluperfect subjunctive:

> "Se saepe rogabat quid bellum similis futurus fuisset."
> =
> "He often asked himself what a war would have been resembling / would have been (like)."

Are these translations correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're making this complicated.
Let's start with:

> *Quale est bellum?*
> What is war like?

In English you structure it differently, but Latin has the convenient interrogative and relative pronoun *qualis* ≈ "like what, of what kind".

You can use *similis*, but that makes it all much more convoluted.
You need to use genitive or dative with that.
You could do:

> *Cui(us) [rei] simile est bellum?*
> To what [thing] is war similar?

This changes the tone of the question — in addition to being a calque of the English.
This is asking to name a thing that war is similar to, not to describe war.
You can answer *quale* by an adjective like *atrox* or a comparison *simile morbi*, but you can only answer *cuius rei simile* with the latter.
I assume you want to ask "what is war like" and not "what is war similar to".

Due to the structuring of the direct question and the choice of case to go with *simile*, I would say that your translations are incorrect.

You should really be using *quale* here.
Only after we have this direct question in place should we embark on a journey towards the more convoluted sentences.
This is an important general strategy:
When you have trouble expressing something, simplify and strip your sentence until you are left with the simplest thing you cannot express.
Find the easiest question you cannot answer, and do not touch the original question before you can answer the simplified one.

The improved direct question is simpler than your (implicit) suggestion, and therefore the indirect versions are simplified as well:

> *Cupiebam scire quale bellum esset.*
> I wanted to know what war is like.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say.

Comment: I believe authors sometimes ask “qualis [gen.] natura est?” in a very similar way. E.g., Caesar sent scouts to determine  “qualis esset natura montis” - what the mountain was like

Comment: @Kingshorsey Do you happen to know of a neuter example of that? Masculine and feminine fail to differentiate between nominative and genitive but neuter doesn't. Asking *qualis naturae est* ("of what nature is it") makes sense as a qualitative genitive, but *qualis [gen!] est* sounds unlikely to me. The qualitative nature of the word is already in the word itself (even etymologically!) so I think only the nominative is used. But as always, classical attestations trump my intuition and I'd be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: Qualis is modifying natura. Cicero: roges me qualem naturam deorum esse dicam. You may ask me what sort of nature I say is [the nature] of the gods —> You may ask me what I say the gods are like.

Comment: I see how my original comment was misleading. “Qualis est natura [gen.]”

Comment: @Kingshorsey Oh, I see. I interpreted that *qualis* would be in the genitive. A genitive to express whose nature is under discussion is indeed normal: Qualis est natura alicuius rei?

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: Thank you. The thinking was that the answer to "What is something like?" can only be couched in terms of what the questioner has already experienced. With war there has almost certainly been no such experience. Therefore, the only (non-) answer is "Go and find out (by experiencing it--God help you).".  Courcey is not asking a direct Q., no answer is solicited; he has come for the experience. I burst out laughing when I watched this scene: it sounded so completely mad! An excellent film: no glory; no flag-waving; "War without Fanfare";  Corporal Courcey achieved his ambition.

Comment: @tony You're welcome! Nonetheless, when you have trouble finding an indirect question, form the direct one first. There really is no excuse not to, even if you are aiming for something indirect in the end. Stripping a question down to its essentials makes them far easier to ask and answer, and that's a good strategy for thinking. I should add that using a word like "like" in situations like this is an English idiom. Many other languages, including Latin, go about such questions, direct or indirect, differently.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: Term "like" has a myriad of uses (Oxford). In Liverpool, it is used to end sentences: "Do you know what I mean, like?" . One final thing if I may, please, is the second example, "se saepe rogabat quale bellum futurus fuisset."?

Comment: @tony Yes, that seems to work well for your second example.

Answer (score 5):

Just an addendum to what Joonas said:

Use *qualis* if you're trying to understand the substance of something. The question "what is war like?" is  how war is, it's texture, what feelings it evokes, how it works, etc. "Like" in this usage is an idiom, and is different from the "like" in similes. Essentially you're looking for the *qualities* (and yes we get "quality" from *qualis*).

On the other hand, *similis* is used for comparisons. You would use that when you want to know what war is *similar to*. War is *like* hell (though Hawkeye knows better). In that example, you would use *similis*:

> *Bellum Tartaro simile sed peius.*

Answer (score 4):

I would translate:

> Bᴀ. Cur voluntarius in Vietnamiam militatum venisti?
> Cᴏ. Ut naturam bellorum cognoscam.

Why the plural? Because I think otherwise it will always be a likely reading that he is talking about the current war.

Comment: I can see this in a dialogue of Cicero or Terence (cf. *Heaut* 503), but probably not Plautus. Given the movie's theme, too bad none of the old Roman tragedies survived intact.